# IndexedDB - Drop database instance created by IndexedDB upon browser clear cache

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-cache, indexeddb

The database instance created by WebSQL API is dropped automatically once browser cache is cleared (*chrome://settings/clearBrowserData*) but when database instance created by IndexedDB API, then it is not dropped upon browser clear cache. So when same domain is navigated then db instance created before browser clear cache can be seen.

I have tried all the techniques mentioned in [how-to-delete-indexeddb-in-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384128/how-to-delete-indexeddb-in-chrome), like going to content setting but they really don't work + they are manual step. I want the cache to be cleared using *chrome://settings/clearBrowserData*, which works well in case of WebSQL.

Only way I could make it work in case of IndexedDB is by programmatically dropping the db instance (*indexedDB.deleteDatabase("my_db_instance")*), but that doesn't fit good in production environment for end users.

Is it a know or unresolved issue? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "Cookies and other site and plug-in data" is checked before hitting the "Clear browsing data" button. If that still doesn't work then please [file a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry) that includes reproduction steps.

Comment: Thank you. I have reported a bug - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477310, let see what happens.